# How to enable anonymous access to custom app page

Tags: 2007, application-pages, anonymous-authentication

I'm trying to make a custom application page which can be viewed by anonymous users. So far I've:

- Inherited the code behind from UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
- Overriden AllowAnonymousAccess to always return true
- Enabled anonymous access for the web application in central admin

but still it requires me to login to see the page. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: There must be something on the page which doesn't allow Anonymous Access! Either a List View Web Part, or any other thing!

Comment: Create a totally blank aspx page as per: http://hughajwood.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/creating-a-blank-aspx-page-for-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/ and see if that works with the anonymous permissions.

Comment: Cheers, that worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it worked, I will post as the answer so it's clear.

> 1) Create a new blank SharePoint 2010 project targeting .net 3.5 framework and any processor and target your test SP2010 site
>
> 2) Add new reference to the SharePoint built in folder _Layouts
>
> 3) I recommend you create a sub folder in here to keep your custom files in nice and neatly, so make an External folder for this example
>
> 4) Add a new Application Page to the External folder and call it blanktest
>
> 5) Delete the designer page (not needed)
>
> 6) In the aspx page delete EVERYTHING but the following two lines:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="blanktest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Your.Namespace.Here" %>
```

> 7) Deploy
>
> 8) Browse to your site http://[site]/_layouts/External/blanktest.aspx

There you have it, a 100% blank aspx page that you can do ANYTHING with.

This method is almost identical to making a ashx HTTP Handler, except instead of inheriting Page you Inherit HTTPHandler with your default function being:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context).
```

Quoted from my blog post [here](http://hughajwood.wordpress.com/2012/11/08/creating-a-blank-aspx-page-for-sharepoint-2010-using-visual-studio-2010/)